# WordPress application password authentication not working

Tags: wordpress

WordPress version 5.9.2

We can not add application passwords in WordPress to call against the API. It shows no password only an empty textbox when I add one.

I know that this is not a good description and may not sound precise, but maybe someone had the same problem. How can I fix application passwords in WordPress? Otherwise can I add it directly into the database?

Comment: Do you mean version 5.9.2?

Comment: When I try to add an application password. I get a "forbidden" message underneath the "Add New Application Password" button. The user has Administrator rights. I have tried disabling WordFence but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yes 5.9.2 edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling plugins.

In my case I had "Simple JWT Login" installed. Deactivating it fixed the issue.

Comment: I think we have another Plugin for JWT installed maybe it also makes some problems. I will check that, thanks.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! It fixed the issue. We had some JWT package installed before, that was the issue.